# React custom component does not accept 2 onClicks

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have one custom button component like the following:

```
export const Button = ({
  children,
  onClick,
  className,
  ...props
}: IButton) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('primary')

  const handleSelected = () => {
    setSelected(selected === 'primary' ? 'selected' : 'primary')
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleSelected} className={cs(className, styles.baseButton, selected)} {...props}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

and I have the other component which is calling this component:

```
export const CustomComponent = ({bookings, selectedBookings}) => {

    const handleSelectedTimeSlot = (startTime, endTime) => {
    selectedBookings({ startTime, endTime })
  }

  {bookings.map((booking) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleSelectedTimeSlot(booking.startTime, booking.endTime)
            }}
          >
            {booking.name}
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
}
```

And I have this GrandParent component which is calling the CustomComponent like this:

```
export const GrandComponent = ({ data }: any) => {

  const [selectedTimeSlots, setSelectedTimeSlots] = React.useState({
    startTime: '',
    endTime: '',
  })

  const handleSelected = ({ startTime, endTime }) => {
    setSelectedTimeSlots({ ...selectedTimeSlots, startTime, endTime })
  }

return (
    <div>
        {selectedTimeSlots.startTime}
      <div>
        {data &&
          data.map(times => (
            <CustomComponent
              key={nanoid()}
              bookings={times.bookings}
              selectedTimeSlots={handleSelectedTimeSlots}
              selected={selectedTimeSlots.selected}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but I have some issues here, when I try to toggle the style of the custom button here, it works BUT only if I remove the `handleSelectedTimeSlot(booking.startTime, booking.endTime)` from the CustomComponent but what I'm trying to do is that I want to apply a custom styles when the button got clicked, also I need to send the from CustomComponent to GrandComponent after I click on the button, but it does not work, toggling styles does not work if I send data from `CustomComponent` to `GrandParentComponent` and I have tried many things, but without luck, any ideas how that could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleSelected = () => {
    setSelected(selected === 'primary' ? 'selected' : 'primary')
    onClick();
  }
```

This will call the passed-in `onClick` function when the button element is clicked.  So you will get to set the element state as well as call the passed-in function.

If this works for you, I would suggest renaming things to better understand at a glance what is going on.  `onClick` is fine when it's local to the element, but as you pass it in from a parent it can become confusing. Maybe not in this case, but certainly as components grow more complex.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts but it didn't work unfortunatly as I have already tried it before, but do you have a better idea as a best practice for more complex example?

Comment: Name the function to exactly what it does. In your example you define ‘handleSelectedTimeslot’ and then you basically redefine it as ‘onClick’.  This is unnecessary since that function is not the actual onClick function for the button element.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you update your GrandComponent from inside of your Button component though the props being passed, it re-renders and since you add a key to CustomComponent directly inside the render it changes when the component re-renders causing the component to remount instead of just re-rendering and hence all child states are reset to the initial state.

What you can do is construct an array with id once

```
export const GrandComponent = ({ data }: any) => {

  const [selectedTimeSlots, setSelectedTimeSlots] = React.useState({
    startTime: '',
    endTime: '',
  })

  const handleSelected = ({ startTime, endTime }) => {
    setSelectedTimeSlots({ ...selectedTimeSlots, startTime, endTime })
  }

  const dataWithId = useMemo(() => data && data.map(d => ({...d, ...(d.id? {}: {id: nanoid()}) })), [data]);

return (
    <div>
        {selectedTimeSlots.startTime}
      <div>
        {dataWithId &&
          dataWithId.map(times => (
            <CustomComponent
              key={times.id}
              bookings={times.bookings}
              selectedTimeSlots={handleSelectedTimeSlots}
              selected={selectedTimeSlots.selected}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: hmm, I understand your way, but unfortunatly it didn't work as well :\

Answer (score 0):

`CustomComponent` is not being passed a `selectedBookings` prop.  So in `handleSelectedTimeSlot` you are calling an `undefined` function.